# Test if mailbox is in use, if it does add a variable to the SMTP name

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Looking to test a new script, pretty much if a users mailbox exist change the SMTP name to include a variable at the end example `John.Doe@mycompany.com` would be changed to `John.Doe1@mycompany.com`. I'm able to test if the mailbox exist with the `Get-Mailbox` or `Get-Recipient` commands but I need a way to output the result and store it in a variable?

Example:

```
if (!(Get-Mailbox 'John.Doe@mycompany.com'))-eq $true {
  Mailbox = 'John.Doe1@mycompany.com
} else {
  Write-Host "Mailbox is available
}
```

Or something along these lines, I don't have any code written yet to upload.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me what you mean by "include a variable at the end", but assigning a value to a variable depending on a condition is fairly simple:

```
$mailbox = if (-not (Get-Mailbox 'John.Doe@mycompany.com')) {
             'John.Doe1@mycompany.com'
           }
```

The above will assign the address `John.Doe1@mycompany.com` to the variable `$mailbox` if no mailbox `John.Doe@mycompany.com` exists. If the mailbox does exist, the value of `$mailbox` will be `$null`.